# LinkedIn Javascript SDK working in Chrome, not Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, linkedin-api

I have the following JS code in my `<head>` tag:

```
<script>
  function hello() {
    alert('blah');
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  onLoad: hello
  api_key: xxxxx
</script>
```

In Chrome (61.0.3163.100), this alert's successfully, but in Safari (11.0 (13604.1.38.1.6)), nothing happens with any console message or anything to go on. Needless to say I am unable to use any SDK functions. I've checked  the network inspector and the SDK is indeed being loaded. I have a very high percentage of Safari users so I can't ignore them. Any suggestions?